# Android - make view overflow visible / render it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-12dp"
        android:alpha=".50"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_two"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The overflow of the ImageView doesn't show but it's cut off beyond the border, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `android:clipChildren="false"` to all ascendants of the *ConstraintLayout* to prevent having children clipped to the borders of their *ViewGroups*.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-12dp"
            android:alpha=".50"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

[image]